# Forward request object(POST) from express js server to another express js server

Tags: node.js, express, post, request, http-proxy

I want to forward a post request from an express server(from inside post method) to another express server's post method.
Is there any way to do that?

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var lb = 'http://localhost:8000';
```

after that inside post,

```
app.post('/emaillist', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);  // printing params correctly
console.log('redirecting to loadbalancer');
console.log(req.body);
apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: lb});
```

Here problem is that I can't retrieve request paramaters/body sent, in loadBalancer server. When trying to retrieve a property(e.g. email) out of request loadBalancer,

```
console.log(req.body.sender);
```

It says cant read a property of undefined.
My question is how to send request to another noder server from a node server and how to retrieve request parameters out of it at receiving node server

Comment: does the proxy server use body parser?

Comment: I am using this advanced-load balancer to receive request from my express application-                                                     https://gist.github.com/goldfire/0faca8894f5bd38c57ce#file-advanced-lb-js                                                                                                                     And then I am forwarding it to 2 servers hosted. Also, I am not getting how to send/receive request parameters to those servers